# Application Uses Command Line Behind the Scenes

Tags: terminal, command-line, applications

I use a gui application that can access the command line to run commands/scripts/etc. Is there a place where these commands are logged? They don't show up in `.bash_history` or `.zsh_history` and I need to debug the commands the application sends to the command line.

[image]

The first line works and creates an empty file. The second line does not work. Probably has to do with the quotes, however that's how this program decided to handle terminal commands. This is why it would be nice to find the actual command that was sent to the command line. MacOS has to log that somewhere right?

Comment: The second line is clearly wrong. Instead of logging, would it help to contact the developer about it?

Comment: No. It would not help to contact the developer about it.

Comment: Which application is it, maybe others here know how to change the behavior?

Comment: Have you used the Console app?

Comment: @Gilby I tried it but there is so much info being logged that I can't filter the noise out.

Comment: @nohillside The app is Simplify3d which is a 3d printer slicer

Comment: https://www.simplify3d.com/ seems to be broadly used and actively developed, it also has a [support site](https://www.simplify3d.com/resources/). It might be worth raising the issue there.

Comment: @nohillside The company is a scam. Already tried their forums.

Comment: I probably missed the topic in the forum then. Having to pay $199 for a software with such issues for sure feels wrong. Anyway, you already have the comment "sent to the command line" in your screenshot, assume this is not enough then. Are there any relevant settings/preferences to control this, or at least change the shell to be used?

Comment: My guess why the touch command works and the echo command does not involves the fact that I have nested quotes in the echo command. For some reason the software wants you to wrap the command in double quotes. When I run commands within the terminal itself, wrapping the command in quotes is not necessary. Just weird formatting stuff going on behind the scenes and theres no way to know what command the software actually sent to the system command line. If I knew that, I would know exactly how to format the command

Comment: Ah, for the command shown it‘s easy: replace the `""` at the beginning with `"` and put a `"` in front of `/Users`.